# Does the size of the file increase when it is transferred to a destination system through a network?

Tags: networking

assume there are 2 systems connected to the same network (modem). one system is the sender and the other is a receiver. when the sender sends any kind of a file to the receiver it is occupying 5000Kb space, no matter how small the sent file is. is this a problem with my code or the network (LAN) that i'm using?

Comment: i would post this to http://serverfault.com/.

Comment: @austin I wouldn't. He mentions his code, so it is clearly a programming question. He shoud post some code here.

Comment: by your logic i'm equally right since he mentioned a network question as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, depending on the file system but in your case since it is always the same size, I've no idea.

Answer (score 0):

The application data is encapsulated in TCP header (20B), iPv4 header (20B) and in Ethernet (14B) on the sender side. The receiver will decapsulate it and at application layer it has the same size as what you have sent.

On Ethernet one segment can contain 1500B -> -tcp -ip -> 1460B application data fits in one packet.

Thus your problem is not caused by the network. Can you post the code on receiver side?

You can use wireshark tool to check your  data on the wire.